# combo box formula item and value

Tags: combobox, return-value, formula

I have the following formula in a Combo Box:

```
var keyObj = getComponent('ACConditionToggle');
var key = keyObj.getSubmittedValue();
if (!key || key==''){
    key = keyObj.getValue();
}
switch(key)
{
case 'Approval':
    return ['% Approval' , 'Approvers']
    break;
case 'Denial':
    return ['% Denial', 'Deniers']
default:
return new Array();
}
```

It works fine, however, I want to have labels different from the value. SO in this case with the label '% Approval' I want a value of 'Percent' and for for 'Approvers' the value of 'Number'
So how do I pass the label and the value from a formula. I can do that with static and get itemLabel and itemValue but how do I differential them in the formula?

Answer (score 0):

after beating my head against the wall I found the answer to be so simple.

```
var keyObj = getComponent('ACConditionToggle');
var key = keyObj.getSubmittedValue();
var rtnArray = new Array();
if (!key || key==''){
    key = keyObj.getValue();
}
switch(key)
{
case 'Approval':
    rtnArray[0]="% Approval|Percent";
    rtnArray[1]="Approver(s)|Number";
    return rtnArray;
    break;
case 'Denial':
    rtnArray[0]="% Denial|Percent";
    rtnArray[1]="Denials(s)|Number";
    return rtnArray;

    break
default:
return new Array();
}
```